# Linked List problem dummy.next different different as head

Tags: python, linked-list

```
# Definition for singly-linked list.
# class ListNode(object):
#     def __init__(self, val=0, next=None):
#         self.val = val
#         self.next = next
class Solution(object):
    def deleteDuplicates(self, head):
        """
        :type head: ListNode
        :rtype: ListNode
        """
        dummy = ListNode()
        dummy.next = head
        while dummy and dummy.next:
            if dummy.val == dummy.next.val:
                dummy.next = dummy.next.next
            else:
                dummy = dummy.next
        return dummy.next
```

So I'm doing one of the Leetcode problem call remove duplicate from sorted list, i created a dummy node which it's next is head, however when i try to test it with head = [1,2,3,3,4,4,5], return dummy.next is giving a empty list as output and return head is giving the correct output, i'm wondering why is that since dummy.next should be equal to head?

Comment: Read [this article](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) for tips on debugging your code.

Comment: Seems that if you stepped through this in a debugger, you'd see pretty quickly what's going on.  Have you done that?  (ha.  typed this before seeing @Code-Apprentice's comment)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 2):

The idea to use this `dummy` is good, but then you shouldn't assign anything else to it. In your loop you should use another name for traversing the list -- not `dummy`: this could be a new name like `curr`, or you could even use `head` for it:

```
        dummy = ListNode()
        dummy.next = head
        while head and head.next:
            if head.val == head.next.val:
                head.next = head.next.next
            else:
                head = head.next
        return dummy.next
```